# Vue 3 SSR Fails with v-for directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, server-side-rendering

I am working on a `Vue 3 + Vite + Vuex + Axios + Vue-Router` SSR application which fetches products list from a NodeJS application.

The application is rendering static data very well, but when it comes to `v-for` it failed wtih mismatch error.

[image]

I am fetching API data in router file using `beforeResolve` hook.
There is a strange thing that if I read data from JSON, things works smoothly. I thought that API is taking too much time to share response, that was reason I used `beforeResolve`. However, it did not resolved the issue.

[image]

Here's my Products component.

```
<template>
    <InnerView pageName="Products">
        <div class="container py-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div v-for="(product, key) in products" :key="key" class="card border-0 col-12 col-md-4 mb-2 product-card">
                    <div class="product-img vertical-center m-md-0 mb-3 col-12">
                        <img :src="`${product.images !== undefined ? getImgOrigin + 'products/' + product.image.trim() : defaultImg}?tr=h-416`" class="img-fluid" :alt="product.name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body border border-black border-0 px-0 pb-2 border-top border-bottom row">
                        <div class="card-text col-12">
                            <template v-for="(item, indx) in Object.keys(product)">
                                <p class="row" v-if="Object.keys(labels).indexOf(item) >= 0" :key="indx">
                                    <span class="col-4 fw-bold" v-text="labels[item]"></span>
                                    <span class="col-8" v-text="product[item]"></span>
                                </p>
                            </template>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 card-link mt-2 text-end">
                            <a class="fs-4 btn btn-enquire px-4 ms-2 btn-success" target="_blank" :href="`${getWhatsappLink}${product.name}`" title="Enquire on WhatsApp">
                                <i class="bx bxl-whatsapp"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a class="fs-4 btn btn-enquire px-4 ms-2 btn-primary" target="_blank" :href="`mailto:${getAppInfo('salesEmail')}`" title="Enquire on E-Mail">
                                <i class="bx bx-mail-send"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="border-0" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </InnerView>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import InnerView from '@/views/InnerView.vue';

export default {
    name: 'Products',
    data() {
        let defaultImg = '/img/placeholder-image.jpg';
        return {
            labels: {
                name: 'Name',
                composition: 'Composition',
                packing_size: 'Packing Size',
                packing_type: 'Packing Type',
                mrp: 'MRP (&#x20B9;)',
                prescription_fl: 'Prescriptive',
                type: 'Type',
                shelf_life: 'Shelf Life (Months)',
                usage: 'Usage',
            },
            products: {},
            type: '',
            loading: true,
            defaultImg
        };
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['getWhatsappLink', 'getAppInfo', 'getImgOrigin']),

        ...mapGetters('Products', ['getProducts', 'getLabels']),

        getProductsList() {
            console.log(this.getProducts)
            return this.getProducts ?? {};
        }
    },

    created() {
        console.log('this.getProducts', this.getProducts)
        this.products = this.getProducts;
    },

    components: { InnerView }
}
</script>
```

It is the `server.js` which renders the html content.

```
export async function createServer () {
const app = express();
const root = process.cwd();
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const hmrPort = 3000;

port = 6170;
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
const resolve = (p) => path.resolve(__dirname, p);

const indexProd = isProd ? fs.readFileSync(resolve('./dist/client/index.html'), 'utf-8') : '';
const manifest = isProd ? JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(resolve('./dist/client/ssr-manifest.json'), 'utf-8')) : {};

/**
* @type {import('vite').ViteDevServer}
*/
let vite;

if (!isProd) {
  vite = await (await import('vite')).createServer({
    base: '/',
    root,
    logLevel: isTest ? 'error' : 'info',
    server: {
      middlewareMode: true,
      watch: {
        usePolling: true,
        interval: 100
      },
      hmr: {
        port: hmrPort
      }
    },
    appType: 'custom'
  });

  app.use(vite.middlewares);
} else {
  app.use((await import('compression')).default());
  app.use('/', (await import('serve-static')).default(resolve('./dist/client'), { index: false }));
}
```

I am seeking for help for fixing this rendering issue with `v-for` directive.